# XML in HTTP response

Tags: java, html, xml

I want to return some HTML code in my XML response. So it will be highlighted on the client side. so for example i have XML response like this

```
<Response id="1234"> <Document> <text>&lt;span style="color:blue;font:18pt" &gt;fevers&lt;/span gt;</text></Document>
</Response>
```

The problem that the client understands this as "`<span>fever</span>`" but not understanding the span itself and highlighting the word "fever". and of course i can't send "<>" in XML as the library translates them directly to their codes. Any help would be appreciated Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose it with [Character Data (CDATA)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA):

```
<![CDATA[<hello>World!</hello>]]>
```

Comment: Yeah thanks, i was looking at it right now :) I will give it a try, it should work i think

Comment: any idea how to put the CDATA with xstream? iam having some error when trying to execute the code you will find on google. Some class cant be found

Comment: ok you just need to download this jar, and then it works like charm:) with the normal code that is found on the internet
[link]http://www.extreme.indiana.edu/dist/java-repository/xpp3/jars/

Answer (score 0):

Base 64 encode it and you'll be able to send that XML - *without* having to deal with a CDATA section on the client side.

Personally, I don't think it's a good idea for servers to know anything about how data is rendered on the client side.  Why should the server enforce what amounts to CSS style?  That's a client issue.

If it must be enforced, make it a governance or communication issue; don't try to do it in code.

Comment: It is a searching mechanism in large documents, so I needed to make a server call to search for text in those documents. Thats why iam enforcing this. As i dont want the client to do the searching by himself. specially if it is an iphone/ipad